# WPF Application crashes on WIndows 7 when command executable.Start() is run

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp, external-process

I've got a tiny Portal I´m writing, and this portal is supposed to launch installers on button click. I´m developing on VS2010 on a WinXP SP3 station, and on this machine, even fter compilation and publishing, everything works as expected. However, when i run the compiled application in Windows 7, it crashes...The application work, it just crashes when i click a button for program installation.

The programming looks like this:

```
    private void button_access_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        Process executable = new Process();
        string executablePath = "D:\\Visual Studio 2010\\SAFE_Portal1\\SAFE_Portal1\\Extra Programs\\AccessRT2003.exe";
        executable.StartInfo.FileName = executablePath;
        executable.Start();


    }
```

It specifically crashes on thr button_access_Click procedure...

Any ideas as to why this could be? I`ve tried looking around here in Stackoverflow, and in other forums, but to no avail...

Any help or direction is ganz welcome!

Comment: You could add a try catch block to that code and output the Exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! 

I added the try catch and it turns out it fails because it cannot find the file specified. the file location specified is always present in my XP machine. Meaning that on my XP machine "D:\\Visual Studio 2010\\SAFE_Portal1\\SAFE_Portal1\\Extra Programs\\AccessRT2003.exe" always exists, so when i transfer the app to win7, on that machine that ap is obviously not present. 

The thing is, I´ve added the .exe files to my solution, but i haven#t figured out how to link the .exes, so that it specifies those files in the solution...any aideas?

Comment: On my images, that i also added to my solution, i can link them as follows:

"Images\image1.jpg"

but since the program filepath requires double slash \\, i´m not sure how to specify it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
try
{
     Process executable = new Process();
     string executablePath = "D:\\Visual Studio 2010\\SAFE_Portal1\\SAFE_Portal1\\Extra Programs\\AccessRT2003.exe";
     executable.StartInfo.FileName = executablePath;
     executable.Start();
 }
 catch (Exception msg)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);
 }
```

What message are you getting?

Are you sure you want to use fixed paths in your application? If so you should at least check if the file you try to start exists beforehand. Otherwise an exception will be thrown which could be the problem here.

```
if (File.Exists(executablePath))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that´s what i just realized as the problem, the fixed path is causing it. In my solution I added these files, how can I tell c# that the file i want is in the solutions folder?

In my solutions folder, it`s in a folder called Extra Programs, and when i compile and publish, the folder goes along with it...

Comment: You can use System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location to get the path of the application. Then use System.IO.Path.Combine to build your filename. I'm writing this out of memory on the bus so be warned.;)